# Need Quick & Dirty DOCX Viewing - PyGTK

Tags: python, ms-word, pygtk, gtk

Need:

- A module containing methods for rendering docx files with formatting.

Requirements:

- PyGTK compatibility
- is not the python-docx module

Comment: You make the assumption that I hadn't done that. I was crowd sourcing the answer after finding the python-docx module via Google. When I couldn't find anything better I came here.

Comment: If you found something, please include it in your question to avoid needless repetition of things you already know.  "I've seen it before" could be avoided. Also, if there are issues, concerns or question with the stuff you already found, please include it in the question, so we can address it.  "crowdsourcing" seems like "please do my work for me" which seems rude to some of us.

Comment: I understand. My question has been revised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

Is about as good as it gets.

Comment: I've seen it before, I need a way of render the xml with formatting included.